# Create a function in R with multi outputs like matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I'm not familiar with R, just a newbie. So I want to translate some code from matlab to R. But I have the problem about the output of function. I want to create a function give output to two specify variable, like this:

```
list[a,b]<-function(var1,var2){
a<-var1 + var2
b<-var1 - var2
return list(a,b)
}
```

But my code is not working, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here but assigning a function to the indices of a list is strange to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have some fundamental misunderstanding about functions in R. Read "An Introduction to R". Also, `return` is a function in R.

```
myfun <- function(var1, var2){
  a <- var1 + var2
  b <- var1 - var2
  return(list(a, b))
}

myfun(1:5, 10:6)
#[[1]]
#[1] 11 11 11 11 11
#
#[[2]]
#[1] -9 -7 -5 -3 -1
```

Comment: I know this way but I want return result on two outputs with different name, not one list variable.

Comment: Each function in R should have just one return value. There are ways to circumvent this rule, but that's bad programming and I won't show you how. It's not necessary anyway, because working with a list is more convenient.

Comment: If you want your output to be named you can `return(list(a=a, b=b))`. That way you can reference the result by name like `result$a`...